# How to aggregate pixel in gdal python?

Tags: python, gdal, merge, geotools, aggregation

I want to aggregate pixel in raster file like Arcgis(picture).
Is this fuction possible in gdal(python) or geotools?
And I want to add option to select representative value(ex.sum, max, average..)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In GeoTools this is handled by the [`CoverageProcessor`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/index.html?org/geotools/coverage/processing/CoverageProcessor.html) which can call one of a list of builtin operations or other user supplied ones:

- Absolute: Replaces the pixel values of an image by their absolute values.
- Add:  Adds two images.
- AddConst: Adds constants to an image.
- Affine:   Performs interpolated affine transform on an image.
- BandMerge:    Merge (possibly multi-banded)images into a multibanded image.
- Convolve: Performs kernel-based convolution on an image.
- CoverageCrop:
- DivideByConst:    Divides an image by constants.
- Exp:  Computes the exponential of the pixel values of an image.
- Extrema:  Finds the maximum and minimum pixel value in each band of an image.
- FilteredSubsample:    Filters and subsamples an image.
- Histogram:    Generates a histogram based on the pixel values within a specific region of an image.
- Interpolate:
- Invert:   Inverts the pixel values of an image.
- Log:  Computes the natural logarithm of the pixel values of an image.
- MaxFilter:    Performs max filtering on an image.
- MedianFilter: Performs median filtering on an image.
- MinFilter:    Performs min filtering on an image.
- Mosaic:   Creates a mosaic of two or more rendered images.
- Multiply: Multiplies two images.
- MultiplyConst:    Multiplies an image by constants.
- Resample:
- Rescale:  Maps the pixels values of an image from one range to another range.
- Scale:    Resizes an image.
- SelectSampleDimension:    null
- SubsampleAverage: Subsamples an image by averaging over a moving window.
- SubtractConst:    Subtracts constants from an image.
- SubtractFromConst:    Subtracts an image from constants.
- Warp: Warps an image according to a specified Warp object.
- Zonal:    Image operator for calculating statistics on various Geometries supporting ROI and No Data
- ZonalStats:   Calculate neighbourhood statistics

For what you describe I would think that [`SubsampleAverage`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/index.html?org/geotools/coverage/processing/CoverageProcessor.html) would be the one you want to start with, followed by [`FilteredSubsample`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/index.html?org/geotools/coverage/processing/CoverageProcessor.html) for more complex ones. There is a [tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/coverage/coverage.html) that explains how the coverage processor works.